# Program that Allows you to add Images generated from LaTeX over PDFs

Tags: pdf

Like the title says, I'm looking for a program that allows me to add (and edit) images generated from LaTeX and add them over multi-page PDFs, while also retaining its formatting. Basically, something similar to DocHub, but with a plugin similar to TexMaths for LibreOffice.

EDIT: I do want to make clear that I'm excluding possible TeX-based solutions. If there is a function of some LaTeX editors/ LaTeX packages that allows me to make draggable LaTeX snippets, I'm all ears.

Comment: What wrong with a LaTeX document with `\includegraphics` and/or `pdfpages`?

Comment: @Fran Nothing really, though I wanted something more of a GUI system with drag/drop.

Comment: Then, as you pointed, you want really Libreoffice Draw, or Scribus, but the question is off-topic here since the source of the PDFs to drag&drop is irrelevant.

Comment: @Fran I tried to use LibreOffice, but it sometimes messed up the formatting. I tried to use Scribus, but Scribus converts the text into images.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it specifically asks for a solution WITHOUT TeX

Comment: @TobiBS I mean, if there is a package of LaTeX that would make text boxes draggable, I'm all ears.